# Dedekind's “reciprocity theorem” of Galois theory

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

Dedekind's “reciprocity theorem” of Galois theory is about the decomposition of ploynomial in extension field.

Suppose we has two irreducible polynomial $f(x),g(x)$ in $K\left[ x \right]$, let $f$ decompose into irreducible factors $f_1\dots f_{\mu}$ over $K(b)$ where $b$ is a root of g, similarly, let g decompose into $g_1\dots g_v$ over $K(a)$. Then we can prove $\mu =v$,and $g_k$ can be recorded in such a way that $
{\rm deg}\left( f_k \right) /{\rm deg}\left( f \right) ={\rm deg}\left( g_k \right) /{\rm deg}\left( g \right)$.

First, I show that $a_i$ and $a_j$ are roots of same $f_k$ if and only if there is a $\sigma$ in the Galois group of $fg=0$ over $K$ with  $\sigma a_i=a_j$ and  $\sigma b=b$, then I don't know how to use the fact, I want to use it to show the ${\rm deg}\left( f_k \right) /{\rm deg}\left( f \right) ={\rm deg}\left( g_k \right) /{\rm deg}\left( g \right)$ both are the proportion of $\sigma$ in the Galois group of $fg=0$ over $K$ which carrying $a$ to a root of $f_k$ (or $b$ to a root of $g_k$).

I know the Galois group of a irreducible ploynomial over $K$ has a transitive action on its root.

Thank you for sharing your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$K[x,y]/(f(x),g(y))\cong K(b)[x]/(\prod_j f_j(x))
\cong \prod_j  K(b)[x]/(f_j(x))
$$
$$\cong K(a)[y]/(\prod_k g_k(y))
\cong \prod_k  K(a)[y]/(g_k(y))$$
Assuming that $f,g$ are separable, the decomposition of $K[x,y]/(f(x),g(y))$ in a product of fields is unique, so it must be that $$K(b)[x]/(f_j(x)) \cong K(a)[y]/(g_{s_j}(y))$$
If $f,g$ are non-separable then it is the decomposition in a product of local rings $K[x,y]/(f(x),g(y))\cong \prod_j  K(b)[x]/(f_j(x)^{e_j})\cong \prod_k  K(a)[y]/(g_k(y)^{d_k})$ which is still unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I have a question why the decomposition of field is unique?

Comment: Because it is given by the maximal ideals